# Covert scala to c++ - list to vector

Tags: c++, scala, c++11

I have the following code in scala

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
def legal_moves(dim: Int, path: Path, x: Pos): List[Pos] = 
{
 List((x._1 + 1, x._2 + 2), 
    (x._1 + 2, x._2 + 1), 
    (x._1 + 2, x._2 - 1), 
    (x._1 + 1, x._2 - 2), 
    (x._1 - 1, x._2 - 2), 
    (x._1 - 2, x._2 - 1), 
    (x._1 - 2, x._2 + 1), 
    (x._1 - 1, x._2 + 2))
}
```

I want to convert it to c++, I have tried to do the following:

```
typedef vector<pair<int,int> > Path;

Path move(const pair<int,int> & passed_Pair)
{

    Path allMoves = 
    (
        ( (get<0>(passed_Pair))+1, (get<1>(passed_Pair))+2),
        ( (get<0>(passed_Pair))+2, (get<1>(passed_Pair))+1),
        ( (get<0>(passed_Pair))+2, (get<1>(passed_Pair))-1),
        ( (get<0>(passed_Pair))+1, (get<1>(passed_Pair))-2),

        ( (get<0>(passed_Pair))-1, (get<1>(passed_Pair))-2),
        ( (get<0>(passed_Pair))-2, (get<1>(passed_Pair))-1),
        ( (get<0>(passed_Pair))-2, (get<1>(passed_Pair))+1),
        ( (get<0>(passed_Pair))-1, (get<1>(passed_Pair))+2)
    );

    return allMoves;
}
```

and I am getting this error message:

> conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘Path {aka
>   std::vector >}’ requested

and I get all the allMoves in red.

If I did it like this

```
Path allMoves = { // as above }
```

I get this error message:

```
> error: could not convert ‘{(((void)(((int)std::get<0ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) + 1)), (((int)std::get<1ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) + 2)), (((void)(((int)std::get<0ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) + 2)), (((int)std::get<1ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) + 1)), (((void)(((int)std::get<0ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) + 2)), (((int)std::get<1ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) - 1)), (((void)(((int)std::get<0ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) + 1)), (((int)std::get<1ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) - 2)), (((void)(((int)std::get<0ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) - 1)), (((int)std::get<1ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) - 2)), (((void)(((int)std::get<0ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) - 2)), (((int)std::get<1ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) - 1)), (((void)(((int)std::get<0ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) - 2)), (((int)std::get<1ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) + 1)), (((void)(((int)std::get<0ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) - 1)), (((int)std::get<1ul, int, int>((* &
> passed_Pair))) + 2))}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to
> ‘Path {aka std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >}’   };
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: You need braces `{}`. C++ is obviously not scala

Comment: @StoryTeller I edited the question showing what is the error message when I try to have it as `{}`. Thanks for your comment

Comment: You need braces not just on the outside. I suggest you start learning C++ in a slightly more structured manner. Simply trying scala-ism's is doomed to fail.

Comment: @StoryTeller It is a coursework, I know the structure of vectors. What do u mean by _You need braces not just on the outside._ ?

Comment: I mean that `{ first, second }` is how you would initialize a single pair, so an initializer list for a vector would be `{ { .. }, { .. }, { .. } }`.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes that worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're C++ syntax is just wrong. You need to learn the syntax to construct objects on the stack and how to use the initializer_list constructor of your vector (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > Path;

Path move(const std::pair<int,int>& passed_Pair)
{
    using std::get;
    Path allMoves
    {
        { get<0>(passed_Pair)+1, get<1>(passed_Pair)+2},
        { get<0>(passed_Pair)+2, get<1>(passed_Pair)+1},
        { get<0>(passed_Pair)+2, get<1>(passed_Pair)-1},
        { get<0>(passed_Pair)+1, get<1>(passed_Pair)-2},

        { get<0>(passed_Pair)-1, get<1>(passed_Pair)-2},
        { get<0>(passed_Pair)-2, get<1>(passed_Pair)-1},
        { get<0>(passed_Pair)-2, get<1>(passed_Pair)+1},
        { get<0>(passed_Pair)-1, get<1>(passed_Pair)+2}
    };

    return allMoves;
}
```